# How to avoid MATLAB crash when opening too many figures?

Tags: java, matlab, heap-memory, jvm-crash

Sometimes I start a MATLAB script and realize too late that it is going to output way too many figures. Eventually I get an

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

which can easily be reproduced on my machine using

```
for i=1:inf
  figure;
end
```

I get to around ~90 figures before it crashes with the standard setting ([Preferences / Java Heap Memory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/brjh09y-1.html#bsemees-1)) of  128 MB Java heap, while doubling the Heap to 256 MB gives me around 200 figures.

*Do you see any way to **avoid** the Java error message?* If there is not enough memory for another figure, I'd like my script to be *told* rather than crash.

Maybe I could have a wrapper for `figure` which (somehow?) checks how much Java heap is available and which refuses to open a new figure if there is not enough space left?

**Update**

Using the answers below, I get a nice graph for how much free Memory Java has:

[image: figure;plot(freeMem/1E6,'x');ylabel('java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.freeMemory [MB]');xlabel('number of empty figures created');]

This was produced using

```
for i=1:inf
    java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.gc
    fprintf('%3.0f: %1.0f Byte free\n',i,java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.freeMemory);
    figure;
end
```

I assume the increase in the beginning means that garbage collection only does a certain effort every time I call it?

**Update 2 - my solution**

Using the help I got here, I implemented the following solution as a `figure.m` which overloads and calls the build-in `figure` command:

```
function varargout=figure(varargin)
memcutoff = 10E6; % keep at least this amount of bytes free
memkeyboard= 3E6; % if memory drops below this, interrupt execution and go to keyboard mode
global refuse_new_figures
if refuse_new_figures
    warning('jb:fig:lowjavamem2','Java WAS memory low -> refusing to create a new figure. To reset, type "global refuse_new_figures ; refuse_new_figures = [];"');
    return
end
freemem=java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.freeMemory;
if freemem < memcutoff 
    fprintf('Free memory is low (%1.0f Bytes) -> running garbace collector...\n',freemem);
    java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.gc
end
freemem=java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.freeMemory;
% fprintf('Free memory is %1.0f Bytes.\n',freemem);
if freemem < memkeyboard
    warning('jb:fig:lowjavamem','Java memory very low -> going into interactive mode. Good luck!');
    keyboard;
end
if freemem < memcutoff
    warning('jb:fig:lowjavamem','Java memory low -> refusing to create a new figure!');
    refuse_new_figures=true;
else
    if nargin > 0
        if nargout > 0
            varargout{1}=builtin('figure',varargin{:});
        else
            builtin('figure',varargin{:});
        end
    else
        if nargout > 0
            varargout{1}=builtin('figure');
        else
            builtin('figure');
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Nice update. I'd vote this up a second time if I could. I wonder whether the increase might be due to Java allocating more memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, I'd suggest setting maximum Java Heap Memory to about 25% of the available RAM, which allows you to open lots of figures (but not infinite numbers). If you cannot do this in the preferences (e.g. b/c you have a Mac like mine), [this solution](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18I2C/) will help - it overrides the preference settings.

The linked solution also tells you how much free java memory you have left, and how much total is available: Run the following commands:

```
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.maxMemory
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.totalMemory
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.freeMemory
```

Unfortunately, a figure doesn't take a fixed amount of Java memory, an empty figure takes much less than one displaying 10k points, and a minimized figure takes less memory than a maximized one. However, if you can estimate the average memory needed per figure, you can indeed write a wrapper for `figure` that checks whether it's likely that this figure will be the last. Alternatively/additionally, you could make the wrapper function minimize all other figures ([see Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/minimize-maximize-figure-window/) for this).

**EDIT** As pointed out by [@Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201272/how-to-avoid-matlab-crash-when-opening-too-many-figures/6201399#6201399), you may also try and perform garbage collection before checking how much memory is available - though I don't know whether Matlab would try that, anyway.

Comment: freeMemory only tells you how much is free now, not how much would be free if you performed a GC.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the free memory, if there is no enough trigger a GC and check again.  If there is still not enough, fail.  You might want to allow 1-10 MB head room.

You can use Runtime.gc() and Runtime.freeMemory();

If you don't set the maximum memory it will make it a percentage of the available memory.

Comment: GC will always occur automatically before a JVM throws an OutOfMemory error, so an explicit call to `Runtime.gc()` is not really necessary to free up space, but surely helps to get corerect figures for the usable memory. One thing to remember ist that the VM decides when to GC, `Runtime.gc()` calls do not in every case cause a garbage collection to occur.

Comment: Matlab will set a maximum java memory available for the program, all one can do is choose how much this should be.

Answer (score 1):

I use the findobj function in my own function 'limfig', where imglimit sets the amount of figures you want to be allowed to open at one time.

```
function y=limfig
imglimit=15;
if length(findobj('type','figure'))<imglimit
    y=figure; 

else
    'too many figures already open'
    return
end
end
```

Save this short code as limfig.m and then in any other code use the line f=limfig instead of f=figure.