# Avoid MATLAB startup warning when overloading buildin functions?

Tags: matlab, suppress-warnings, overloading

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201272/how-to-avoid-matlab-crash-when-opening-too-many-figures), I created my own `figure.m` which nicely overloads the built-in `figure` command. Now, whenever I start MATLAB I get the warning

> Warning: Function C:\somepath\figure.m has
>   the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We
>   suggest you rename the function to
>   avoid a potential name conflict.

Is there any way to deactivate this warning, given that it is desired behavior in my case?

You might say that I should call my function differently instead of overloading, but I do feel for my development system this overloading is the right way to go...

**Update**

As mentioned by Aabaz you can globally turn off this warning using

```
warning off MATLAB:dispatcher:nameConflict
```

which needs to go at the beginning of `matlabrc.m` (before the path is set). However, I would still be interested in a solution which could *specificially* remove this error message for overloading figure.m (or some self-defined list of functions) instead of for all functions. I guess I'm asking a bit too much here ;-) ?

Comment: Alternatively you can hide your implementation of `figure` in `C:\somepath\private`, which makes it visible to the functions in `somepath` only. Thus, you avoid the name conflict and potentially unexpected behavior when you work on a different project that is on `someotherpath`.

Comment: @Jonas interesting, I'll give that a try! I would have to add it to a handfull of different paths, but that might indeed be a good option for me.

Comment: MATLAB should have probably better designed the we organize path/scope and implemented some sort of namespaces or modules (similar to what other languages offers)... 

That said, MATLAB does have a "package" functionality, but it seems to have been added as an afterthought, to overcome the problem of namespace collisions. http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brfynt_-1.html 

Other mechanisms to control scope exist such as: private functions, nested and sub-functions.  Check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2748302

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot seem to replicate this warning with my Matlab version (R2008b) but anyway If you did not already try it you should look into the functions [lastwarn](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/lastwarn.html) and [warning](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/warning.html) that allow you to identify and turn off this warning.

PS: the warning eventually came for some reason and I was able to use lastwarn and warning to turn it off.

```
>>[msgstr msgid]=lastwarn;
>>disp(msgid);
MATLAB:dispatcher:nameConflict
>>warning('off',msgid);
```

I should add that you should turn it off at [startup](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/startup.html) for this to be effective between different sessions of Matlab.

Comment: Using lastwarn is a good idea, didn't think of that. However since the warning is generated early during startup (when the directory containing my `figure.m` is added to the path), adding warning off to startup.m was not enough - I needed to place it at the beginning of the global matlabrc.m before the MATLAB path is set.

Comment: Yes you are right, my Matlab installation does not show this warning every time which is strange, but as you said you could do it in **matalbrc.m**. For your specific problem I guess that you could overload the `warning` function in the same way you overloaded the `figure` function in order to specifically turn off this warning for a set of given functions.

Comment: Since `msgstr` contains the name of the function that is being overloaded, overloading `warning` could in principle work. However, I would be very surprised if MATLAB would actually *call* the overloaded `warning.m` without issuing a warning about overloading it first... a kind of chicken-and-egg problem. Of course you could solve that with a `warning off MATLAB:dispatcher:nameConflict; setmypath; warning on MATLAB:dispatcher:nameConflict` trick, but that starts to get rather dirty ;-).

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem on MATLAB R2014b where I also wanted to override `figure`. I think this is the closest solution to your updated question (3.5 years later...).

I think using the "dirty" trick from your comment is actually the cleanest, if done smartly as it doesn't require you to change `matlabrc.m` and can suppress the warning for only functions that you **want** to override built-in ones.

1. Put all your default overrides in a folder that is not on your permanent MATLAB path. I keep mine in `~/Documents/MATLAB/overrides` on my Mac. I have e.g. `~/Documents/MATLAB/overrides/figure.m`
2. Use `startup.m` to add overrides to your path with the warning turned off, and then turn it back on:

```matlab
    warning off MATLAB:dispatcher:nameConflict
    addpath('/Users/victor/Documents/MATLAB/overrides');
    warning on MATLAB:dispatcher:nameConflict
```

<sup>Not sure if tilde expansion works with `addpath` so I write the full path out.</sup>

Doing it this way suppresses the warning for me selectively only for the stuff that gets loaded from `overrides`. You can, of course, be even more selective with your folder naming. It also means I don't have to change anything in my MATLAB system files so it's localized to my user account and persistent across upgrades (for good or bad; monkey patch responsibly).

To access the built-in `figure` from my override, I have to `cd` there temporarily (as otherwise the override will simply call it self). So `figure.m` would look like this:

```matlab
function fig = figure(varargin)

% Call original figure function
old = pwd;
cd(fullfile(matlabroot, 'toolbox', 'matlab', 'graphics', ''));
fig = figure(varargin{:});
cd(old);

% ...
% Do dirty override magic

end
```

Comment: use `builtin` to call the original `figure`, see [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/builtin.html).

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so I'll just expand the answer given by *vicvicvic* further here. The general process stays the same, however it has some further fine tunings.

1. Put your override-function figure.m in a folder which is not on your current MATLAB `path`, e.g. `/users/heidelberg/.matlab/_overload`. For me, tilde expansion is supported, but I would not rely on it. However, you could also put it in a subfolder of a MATLAB startup script (see below).
2. Use `startup.m` to add your override folder to the path. To avoid the warning, make sure it is turned off, and then **restore** its original state

   ```
   % save the current state while switching it off
   warningState = warning('off', 'MATLAB:dispatcher:nameConflict'); 

   addpath('/users/heidelberg/.matlab/_overload');

   % restore the saved state
   warning(warningState);

   % cleanup
   clear('warningState');
   ```

   The difference here is that if e.g. your administrator set the warning to be off anyway, you won't accidentally switch it back on.
3. In your implementation of figure, at some point you will probably have to call the builtin version. *vicvicvic* suggested a `cd` to the directory, however there also is the MATLAB function `builtin`, which does that job for you:

   ```
   function fig = figure(varargin)
   % overload function

   % call builtin figure
   varargout = cell(1, nargout);
   [varargout{:}] = builtin('figure', varargin{:});

   % do you magic here
   % ...

   end
   ```

   Also, use `varargout` and `nargout` to preserve for an arbitrary number of output arguments (might be irrelevant here and now, but for other functions or future releases it might be important).

---

**Annotation**

A method I prefer is to have a subfolder in the directory where my `startup.m` file is stored, called e.g. `_overload`. For me this is `/users/timm/Documents/MATLAB/_overload`. To easily add this folder, use the following script:

File `/users/timm/Documents/MATLAB/startup.m`

```
    % extract the current directory (pwd can fail if started elsewhere)
    [currentPath, ~, ~] = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));

    % add the path, compare above
    warningState = warning('off', 'MATLAB:dispatcher:nameConflict');
    addpath([currentPath, filesep(), '_overload']);
    warning(warningState);

    % cleanup
    clear('currentPath', 'warningState');
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a directory that contains the function overload to the search path will display the warning whenever a function in that directory is edited and saved, no matter if the directory is added in startup.m or not.

A simple way to solve this is to put overloading functions in a [package](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html). Then [import](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html) the package in startup. No need to mess with warnings.