# How to interrupt MATLAB IDE when it hangs on displaying very large array?

Tags: matlab, ide, freeze

Suppose I'm using the MATLAB IDE and happen to have some very large objects in my workspace (e.g. arrays of 500k+ elements). Now, suppose that I stupidly and accidentally double click on one of these very large variables, which triggers a load to the array editor. Unfortunately, with arrays this big, MATLAB just hangs.

I've tried CTRL+C, CTRL+BREAK, CTRL+D, but none seem able to interrupt the behavior of the IDE. I know I can force matlab to quit, but reading all of those variables into the workspace in the first place takes a lot of time, and I may have unsaved changes in an editor window, etc.

Comment: use commandline matlab, so you can't click on the matrices :p

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that behavior modification would be useful, but I do like the IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way, but it's not the best, it requires a change of path and back once to get a handle to the original `openvar`

```
function openvar(name,array)
    persistent org_openvar
    if isempty(org_openvar)
        curdir=pwd;
        cd(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox/matlab/codetools'));
        org_openvar = @openvar;
        cd(curdir);
    end

    if numel(array)>1e5
        if strcmp(questdlg(sprintf('Opening ''%s'' which has %d elements.\n\nAre you sure? This is gonna take a while!',name,numel(array)), ...
        'Variable editor','Yes','Cancel','Cancel') , 'Yes')
                org_openvar(name,array)
            end
    else
        org_openvar(name,array)
    end
end
```

getting that handle is the biggest problem, calling it is just fine. If `openvar` would be built in, you could use the function [builtin](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/builtin.html):

```
builtin('openvar',name,array)
```

but this is unfortunately not the case :(
[str2func](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/str2func.html) in combination with the complete path also doesn't work, at least I don't get it to work...

Comment: I'm adding these links for future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408759/avoid-matlab-startup-warning-when-overloading-buildin-functions

and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201272/how-to-avoid-matlab-crash-when-opening-too-many-figures which has the same solution altough it's for a build in function

Comment: Finally went to test your solution. Nice work! I suggested a small edit so that you build up fullfile in line five using no slashes, otherwise it won't work on Linux systems (where I tested it). This will definitely save me some lost matlab sessions!

Comment: @DanielKessler You're right, I once looked in `fullfile` and noticed the `f = strrep(f,'/','\');` call at the bottom, but from then on I only remembered there was a strrep, not that that line only fixes things from unix to pc. Thanks for making me fix this! I rely too much on `fullfile` for these kind of things and also use both unix and windows :p (It seems your edited was wrongfully rejected, fixed it myself)

Answer (score 5):

The variable editor is launched using the command `openvar`.  To solve your problem you can take advantage of a Matlab quirk that causes functions to be masked by variables with the same name. For example if you create a variable named `plot` the `plot()` function stops working.

The solution, although hackish, is to simply create an empty variable named `openvar`.  Then anytime attempt to open the variable editor will fail because the function `openvar` is being hidden by the variable.

If you want to use the  variable editor again simple call `clear openvar` to delete the variable and the function will be unmasked.

Comment: So the idea is to basically make it harder to open the variable editor in the first place, thus preventing a single double click from crashing things down? Clever approach :), worked for me.

Comment: why not write another openvar function (your own) that wraps the real openvar function. This way you can add a check in there for large matrices and ask the user "are you sure? this is gonna take a while!"

Comment: @GuntherStruyf If I want my custom openvar function to run several checks, and if it passes them, then call the default openvar, how do I go about the call so that it accesses the built-in openvar, rather than getting stuck in a loop.

Comment: @DanielKessler I'm looking for that right now, should be possible imo

Comment: @GuntherStruyf there was a post on http://undocumentedmatlab.com/ describing how to do it. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @DanielKessler: the easiest solution most likely is to simply copy the contents of `openvar` into your modified function (`edit openvar`, the rest should be obvious).

Comment: If it was builtin, things would be easier, tried a lot of things, but next to this problem, `openvar` can't find the original variable when called not from the commandline. So best solution here imo is to copy everything out of the original `openvar.m` to your new file.. Anyways, feature request pending: 'calling any shadowed function'

Comment: @GuntherStruyf I figured it out. I'll post it as a separate question and answer and then link to here.

Comment: see this for how I did it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781634/how-to-wrap-a-built-in-funciton-with-a-new-function-of-the-same-name

Comment: Thanks for the link @slayton! Looks like both helpful question and answers there (both upvoted).