# How to get a handle to an overriden built-in function?

Tags: built-in, overriding, function-handle, matlab

On my Matlab path there's a custom `zeros` function. I want to store a handle to the built-in `zeros` in a variable. How can I do that?

Thought about `@(varargin)builtin('zeros',varargin{:})`, but this would probably slow down the operation due to the string comparison.

Also, I've noticed that it's possible to refer to `diag` as `@numel\diag`, but this doesn't seem to work with other built-in functions (`zeros` in particular).

Comment: What would be the purpose of doing this? Why not call your custom function something different and save yourself the trouble?

Comment: possible duplicate, but not exactly the same: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781634/how-to-wrap-an-already-existing-function-with-a-new-function-of-the-same-name) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727141/how-to-select-a-specific-m-function-when-two-exist)

Comment: What do you mean with 'slow down the operation due to string comparison'?? They're is just one extra step by using `builtin` and that's the function `builtin` itself, the argument expansion imo takes no extra steps

Comment: @MZimmerman6, the purpose is to create a wrapper that chooses between the builtin zeros and gpuArray.zeros.

Comment: @GuntherStruyf, by slow down i mean that it would impose a string comparison an additional function call every time I call zeros.

Comment: @MichaelLitvin That string comparison can't be that bad. It will only add a few millisecond at max

Comment: Yeah that could be a solution, but there's no need. It's not a duplicate as here I was looking for the handle, and there just to call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this doesn't give you an exact answer to your question, but it could solve the problem:

I think this seems to be a good solution:

[matlabcentral: How to call a shadowed function](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/264354)

Withn the last post:

> Just stumbled upon this problem and found the following solution: For
>   example, I have matlab svmtrain shadowed by libsvm toolbox:
>
> > > which svmtrain -all
> > >
> > > C:\Projects\Ichilov\Misc\MVPA\libsvm-mat-3.0-1\svmtrain.mexw64
> > >
> > > C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009b\toolbox\bioinfo\biolearning\svmtrain.m
> > >       % Shadowed
>
> But I can access the original function by using str2func:
>
> > > org_svmtrain = str2func([matlabroot '\toolbox\bioinfo\biolearning\svmtrain'])
>
> and then simply calling:
>
> > > org_svmtrain(training, groupnames)

Comment: Calling `str2func` with the full path throws an 'undefined function' error, but in my particular case calling `str2func('zeros')` did the trick.

Comment: @GuntherStruyf :) this would be just calling the custom-one :o

Comment: In my particular case it would call the builtin func, because my 'zeros' if a field in a class.

Answer (score 4):

**Suggestion #1**

```
% At the beginning of your script:
rmpath('C:\the\folder\containing\the\custom\zeros');
builtInZeros = @zeros;
addpath('C:\the\folder\containing\the\custom\zeros');

% Calling the custom zeros later:
a = zeros(10, 20);

% Calling the built-in zeros:
b = builtInZeros(10, 20);
```

**Suggestion #2**

Put these three lines into your [startup file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html#brlkmbe-1):

```
rmpath('C:\the\folder\containing\the\custom\zeros');
builtInZeros = @zeros;
addpath('C:\the\folder\containing\the\custom\zeros');
```

**Suggestion #3**

It's definitely a dangerous idea to reuse the name of a built-in function. It ruins the readability of your scripts, making them much more difficult to maintain. So if you have control over the custom `zeros` function, then rename it to something else. Use a name which describes how the custom version is different from the built-in one (for example, call it `fastZeros` if it's faster).